# Set a property value took from existing property WPF ControlTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, controltemplate

I'm working on WPF ControlTemplates. 
I want to say whenever the mouserover event was fired on my Buttons, their background colors turn to their borderBrush Color.

```
 <Style TargetType="Button">
     <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
     <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
     <Setter Property="Template">
         <Setter.Value>
             <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                 <Grid>
                     <Border x:Name="Border" CornerRadius="6" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                         <TextBlock x:Name="ContentBlock" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" VerticalAlignment="Center"  HorizontalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
                     </Border>
                 </Grid>
                 <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                     <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                         <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray"></Setter>
                         <Setter TargetName="ContentBlock" Property="Foreground"  Value="Gray"></Setter>
                     </Trigger>
                     <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                         <!--<Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Border.BorderBrush"></Setter>-->
                     </Trigger>
                 </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
             </ControlTemplate>
         </Setter.Value>
     </Setter>
 </Style>
```

in below line, i have tried to take borderBrush from my Button. but i can't do this way:

```
 <!--<Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Border.BorderBrush"></Setter>-->
```

Comment: You should use binding instead of just giving the path in value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create `Binding` with `RelativeSource` set to the `Border` itself, which allows you to bind to `Border`'s own `BorderBrush` property:

```
<Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=BorderBrush}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think It is no easy solution to set reference value in the trigger.
       Is it an issue if you set the value with a colour, the way you are setting for the background.

```
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" 
     Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray"></Setter>
                            <Setter TargetName="ContentBlock" 
    Property="Foreground"  Value="Gray"></Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" 
    Property="Background" Value="Gray" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```